# spring and commons configuration

Tags: spring, struts2, startup

I am using the commons configuration api for managing the application configuration and start up parameters.

This is a web based application with Struts 2 and  Spring 3 in my project.

- Does spring or struts have any facilities for reading configuration so I can use it instead of commons configuration
- What is the best approach to initiate and use commons configuration bean with Spring 3 and how can i access it in my Struts 2

Please help me by configuring spring and beans with annotations !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring can read properties files (and read system en environment variables as well) no problem. For this there is a [PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) which can read properties files.

In newer versions of Spring there is a [PropertySource](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/15/spring-3-1-m1-unified-property-management/) abstraction and [Environment](http://blog.springsource.com/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/) abstraction which can be used (there is a special placeholder-configurer which adds support for that as well). With the new PropertySource support properties can come from properties files, command line properties, environment properties, servlet context or JNDI (those are the ones supported out of the box).

With either of these you can simply use placeholders (${...}) together with the `@Value` annotation (or in xml) to replace the placeholders at runtime.

```
public class MyClass {
  @Value(${some.propertyname:defaultValue})
  String property
}
```

Comment: so according to your post there is no need to use the commons configuration any more!

Comment: @AlirezaFattahi There hasn't been for years using Spring. S2 has other configuration mechanisms as well, although CC is a decent solution for some specific purposes. In either case, CC may still be better if you're using custom configurators or have existing code. Otherwise I'd consider just moving to JSON anyway.

Comment: I also found that spring place holder does not support the sources provided in commons configuration. Can you please comment how should  I initial the commons config bean in spring

Comment: Which sources do you have that arent' supported? You can still write your own extensions and hook them up with the spring classes.

Comment: These are all sources which are supported by CC our of the box
PROPERTIES FILES, XML DOCUMENTS, PROPERTY LIST FILES (PLIST), JNDI, JDBC DATASOURCE ,SYSTEM PROPERTIES
SERVLET PARAMETERS, WINDOWS INI
Not all of them supported on the spring

Comment: Correct they aren't all supported but do you need all of them? The most common I encounter in real live are properties (files, environment en system and sometimes from database), jndi and xml. A windows ini file is basically a properties file and is as such perfectly supported. The only I can see out of the list which aren't supported out of the box are a DataSource and PLIST all the others are supported out of the box.